# Get readable format from public key

Tags: public-key

I have o convert an public key in redable format.

I have this public key

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA3qRkBn/pouirEVL/H+at
FLbB1Wmm41Y/4REbuNwMkPNGHhTwVNF4mSvUFdK6L0SYZ8f8B1oe6YzfZ+bWBAde
oiupY6ABHJ8xGkb14RBwFm152kUT29jXXKU9N8aKGsWayOO7ZLIMOnFrWrjIrrLa
NSkKfuCxywOInjcpkuaq/c+cdxKIDTw1QsUrz3rN1s/TJsvfY+oeFtzCh1auE2dQ
dVPxSeK1ApMsXsXfUP85UNloGlruSrf2IyxK33trNGigH2qD/1PHcjft8PiG00gD
9R2DR0bBASpz/CYKEm6Ry37lVJif0OtQKnyVTap4yLuWaMlZiFaSfBh0FlueHLxN
QwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I wanted extract JWK from this public key like this

```
{
  "kty": "RSA",
  "n": "3FCW9xBBsviZUQnDlcZczC_GO0J0Vhzx1VUj_JyM8hTBzJ_--1GHH5k60OHz169jEHgJ9kkwIKP0ld8Ah5-6x1z5a_Vh-uFizbPn45MgUjwuEL2VPeZsn_wPb2t-A6otOR5zUNU_n4xXcjqZETpvEjFQFQ2n_SDujZUMtQfda9f_plTaekqws4iWIr2sA4QNXXSvv6JvWmjp49N6AQexrVRW9XFBkEFpqofwdWkJMU9TJThzzZB--GA8f4CHfD_DsX_aOsM1u1oCmjWiKmz793NhDQChY0LApEjosTm9a0kQuYEEfGrLNiLfplIsXq6Qw4lFCiWDv553J4_nJusAsw",
  "e": "AQAB",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "use": "sig"
}
```

How can i covert this public key and get JWK using terminal or any other tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can use authlib library + python3
https://authlib.org/

```
from authlib.jose import jwk
rsa_key={
    'public_key':'-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA3qRkBn/pouirEVL/H+at\nFLbB1Wmm41Y/4REbuNwMkPNGHhTwVNF4mSvUFdK6L0SYZ8f8B1oe6YzfZ+bWBAde\noiupY6ABHJ8xGkb14RBwFm152kUT29jXXKU9N8aKGsWayOO7ZLIMOnFrWrjIrrLa\nNSkKfuCxywOInjcpkuaq/c+cdxKIDTw1QsUrz3rN1s/TJsvfY+oeFtzCh1auE2dQ\ndVPxSeK1ApMsXsXfUP85UNloGlruSrf2IyxK33trNGigH2qD/1PHcjft8PiG00gD\n9R2DR0bBASpz/CYKEm6Ry37lVJif0OtQKnyVTap4yLuWaMlZiFaSfBh0FlueHLxN\nQwIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'
}
print(jwk.dumps(rsa_key['public_key'], kty='RSA'))
```

notice there is a `\n` at end of each line of the key

Comment: Cant i do this using terminal or any other online tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C# then the following [here](https://gist.github.com/nanasess/ff8629c476edfddc1b304f9759b9eaa3) solution could be helpful for you.

Comment: Cant i do this using terminal or any other online tool.

Comment: May be the following link https://irrte.ch/jwt-js-decode/pem2jwk.html would work for you as you want an online tool regarding your need.